# Fourier transform of delta function $\delta(x)$ and my defined function $s_1(x)$ and $s_2(x)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

$\delta(x)$ and $s_1(x)$ are $0$ if $x\not=0$, if $x=0$, then $\delta(x)=+\infty$ and $s_1(x)=1$, respectively. $s_2(x)=1$ if $1\geq x\geq -1$, otherwise $s_2(x)=0$.

What is the Fourier transform of them?

Comment: The Fourier transform of what? Of all 3 signal separately, or of some product, etc.?

Comment: hah, 3 signal separately.

Comment: OK, but that's pretty straightforward. I mean, what have to tried and where are you stuck? Any Fourier transform table will tell you the result (for $\delta(x)$ and $s_2(x)$). For $s_1(x)$ you could think of what happens to it under an integral.